# referencing same row in multiple joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a mySQL db named relOwner that has two columns:
OwnerID, RelationshipOwner

I am writing a query with joins that references the db:

```
$query = "SELECT b.Contact, b.ContactB, relOwner.OwnerID, relOwner.RelationshipOwner 
    FROM b 
    Left JOIN relOwner
    ON b.Contact = relOwner.OwnerID
    Left JOIN relOwner
    ON b.ContactB = relOwner.OwnerID
";
```

How do I reference the values of RelationshipOwner individually in my php?

```
$RelationshipOwner = $row['RelationshipOwner'];
$RelationshipOwnerB = $row['RelationshipOwner']; <--- Get value from second JOIN
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly then you should probably be using column aliases. You are using two tables. What do they look like? Also, you should not `JOIN` the same table twice, you should use `AND` instead.

Comment: Table b has 2 columns: Contact and ContactB, both integers that correlate to the OwnerID column of the relOwner table.

Comment: why don`t you use two separate queries with one join for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have two foreign key columns on table `b` to table `relOwner` (viz `Contact` and `ContactB`).

As per Sverri's comment, you will need to use a different alias for the tables (I've used `ro1` and `ro2`) , and project different names from the different table columns (e.g. prefix the second table columns with `ro2`):

```
SELECT b.Contact, b.ContactB, ro1.OwnerID, ro1.RelationshipOwner, 
   ro2.OwnerID as ro2OwnerId, ro2.RelationshipOwner as ro2RelationshipOwner
FROM b -- Is this table Contact? If so then "Contact b"
  Left JOIN relOwner ro1
  ON b.Contact = ro1.OwnerID
  Left JOIN relOwner ro2
  ON b.ContactB = ro2.OwnerID;
```

Which you can then reference:

```
$row['ro2RelationshipOwner'];
```

Comment: Didn't get it to work yet, but is this right: ro1.RelationshipOwner as ro2RelationshipOwner?

Comment: Oops - well spotted. No its supposed to be `ro2.RelationshipOwner as ro2RelationshipOwner` - I've fixed